# How to enable Authentication on Asp Classic application running on Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, asp-classic

I'm facing a strange request.

We have an ASP CLASSIC application, and there is the need to make it run under Azure, with Active Directory authentication.

Is this even possible?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: have you considered running it on a VM in Azure or is that not an option?

Comment: Was not an option, but found the solution inside ther app service :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

1. Using the editor in the App Service, and upload all the files of the ASP website
2. Enable Authentication through Microsoft Provider in the app service
3. On Azure Active Directory, in the Registered App, is possible to create groups and add user to be enabled to access the website